# Hide default information, google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if there is the option of hiding some information that google shows you by default, as subway stations, or public spaces names. I've been searching the web but few comments I have found. I don't want to display some transports info.

Does google maps api 3 allows you to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Maps API V3 does allow you to remove or change information using Styled Maps:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling